# Issues with building Google V8 versions 10.x/11.x with Visual Studio 2019 (9.x is ok)

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8, gn

I'm currently having issues to build V8 version 11.x on Windows,
specifically every version beyond 10.0 does not build on Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.22) due to different build errors.
**V8 version 9.99 builds for me successfully using the steps described below.**

**Does V8 above version 10 still support a Visual Studio build, or has the V8 team switched to using clang on Windows entirely?**
Because from the build issues of the 10.x or 11.x versions I get the impression that V8 is not CI tested on Visual Studio anymore.

I'm further explaining my issues in detail on the example of V8 version **11.1.55 (f7c642b0d7)**.

I set my environment variables as following:

```
set vs2019_install=[path to your \Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community]
set WINDOWSSDKDIR=[path to your \Windows Kits\10]
set DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0
```

I invoke the build with following commands:

```
cd v8
git checkout 11.1.55
gclient sync
gn args out/x64.debug
ninja -C out/x64.debug v8_monolith
```

Following arguments are passed to gn (when the editor opens due to gn args)

```
is_component_build = false
is_debug = true
symbol_level = 0
target_cpu = "x64"
use_goma = false
v8_enable_backtrace = false
v8_enable_fast_mksnapshot = true
v8_enable_slow_dchecks = true
v8_optimized_debug = true
enable_iterator_debugging = true
v8_static_library = true
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
use_custom_libcxx = false
is_clang = false
use_lld = false
use_cxx17 = true
```

The first build error is:

```
[816/1906] CXX obj/v8_compiler/js-native-context-specialization.obj
FAILED: obj/v8_compiler/js-native-context-specialization.obj
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133
\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe" /c ../../src/compiler/js-native-context-specialization.cc /Foobj/v8_compiler/js-native-context-spec
ialization.obj /nologo /showIncludes -DUSE_AURA=1 -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS -D_HAS_EXCEPT
IONS=0 -D__STD_C -D_CRT_RAND_S -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_ATL_NO_OPENGL -D_WINDOWS -DCERT_CHAI
N_PARA_HAS_EXTRA_FIELDS -DPSAPI_VERSION=2 -DWIN32 -D_SECURE_ATL -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_M
EAN -DNOMINMAX -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -DNTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_WIN10_FE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -DWINVER=0x0A00 -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_
ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DCPPGC_VERIFY_HEAP -DENABLE_DISASSEMBLER -DV8_TYPED_ARRAY_MAX_SIZE_IN_HEAP=64 -DOBJECT_PRINT -DVERIFY
_HEAP -DV8_TRACE_MAPS -DV8_ENABLE_ALLOCATION_TIMEOUT -DV8_ENABLE_FORCE_SLOW_PATH -DV8_ENABLE_DOUBLE_CONST_STORE_CHECK -DV8_I
NTL_SUPPORT -DENABLE_HANDLE_ZAPPING -DV8_CODE_COMMENTS -DV8_ENABLE_DEBUG_CODE -DV8_ENABLE_HEAP_SNAPSHOT_VERIFY -DV8_SNAPSHOT
_NATIVE_CODE_COUNTERS -DV8_ATOMIC_OBJECT_FIELD_WRITES -DV8_ENABLE_LAZY_SOURCE_POSITIONS -DV8_SHARED_RO_HEAP -DV8_WIN64_UNWIN
DING_INFO -DV8_ENABLE_REGEXP_INTERPRETER_THREADED_DISPATCH -DV8_SHORT_BUILTIN_CALLS -DV8_EXTERNAL_CODE_SPACE -DV8_ENABLE_MAG
LEV -DV8_ENABLE_SYSTEM_INSTRUMENTATION -DV8_ENABLE_ETW_STACK_WALKING -DV8_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY -DV8_ALLOCATION_FOLDING -DV8_AL
LOCATION_SITE_TRACKING -DV8_ADVANCED_BIGINT_ALGORITHMS -DV8_STATIC_ROOTS -DV8_USE_ZLIB -DV8_ENABLE_WASM_SIMD256_REVEC -DV8_E
NABLE_CHECKS -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS_IN_SHARED_CAGE -DV8_31BIT_SMIS_ON_64BIT_ARCH -DV8_ENABLE_SANDBOX
-DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DV8_IMMINENT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DCPPGC_CAGED_HEAP -DCPPGC_YOUNG_GENERATION -DCPPGC_POINTER_COM
PRESSION -DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64 -DV8_HAVE_TARGET_OS -DV8_TARGET_OS_WIN -DDEBUG -DENABLE_SLOW_DCHECKS -DV8_RUNTIME_CALL_STATS -
DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD=0 -DUSE_CHROMIUM_ICU=1 -DU_ENABLE_TRACING=1 -DU_ENABLE_RESOURCE_TRACING=0 -DU_STA
TIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DICU_UTIL_DATA_IMPL=ICU_UTIL_DATA_FILE -I../.. -Igen -I../../include -Igen/include -I../../third_party/i
cu/source/common -I../../third_party/icu/source/i18n /WX /wd4244 /Gy /FS /bigobj /utf-8 /Zc:sizedDealloc- /wd4117 /D__DATE__
= /D__TIME__= /D__TIMESTAMP__= /MDd /wd4245 /wd4267 /wd4324 /wd4701 /wd4702 /wd4703 /wd4709 /wd4714 /wd4715 /wd4718 /wd4723
/wd4724 /wd4800 /wd4506 /wd4091 /wd4127 /wd4251 /wd4275 /wd4312 /wd4324 /wd4351 /wd4355 /wd4503 /wd4589 /wd4611 /wd4100 /wd4
121 /wd4244 /wd4505 /wd4510 /wd4512 /wd4610 /wd4838 /wd4995 /wd4996 /wd4456 /wd4457 /wd4458 /wd4459 /wd4200 /wd4201 /wd4204
/wd4221 /wd4245 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4389 /wd4702 /wd4701 /wd4703 /wd4661 /wd4706 /wd4715 /O2 /Ob2 /Oy- /Zc:inline /Gw /std:c+
+17 /TP /GR- /std:c++17 /Fd"obj/v8_compiler_cc.pdb"
../..\src/execution/isolate-data.h(279): error C2607: static assertion failed
../..\src/execution/isolate-data.h(281): error C2607: static assertion failed
../..\src/execution/isolate-data.h(284): error C2607: static assertion failed
../..\src/execution/isolate-data.h(286): error C2607: static assertion failed
```

Another build error is the following:

```
[4/1099] CXX obj/v8_compiler/js-operator.obj
FAILED: obj/v8_compiler/js-operator.obj
ninja -t msvc -e environment.x64 -- "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133
\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe" /c ../../src/compiler/js-operator.cc /Foobj/v8_compiler/js-operator.obj /nologo /showIncludes -DUSE
_AURA=1 -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -D__STD_C -D_CRT_RAND_S -D_CRT_SECU
RE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_ATL_NO_OPENGL -D_WINDOWS -DCERT_CHAIN_PARA_HAS_EXTRA_FIELDS -DPSAPI_VERSION=2
-DWIN32 -D_SECURE_ATL -DWINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_DESKTOP_APP -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DNOMINMAX -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -DNTDD
I_VERSION=NTDDI_WIN10_FE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00 -DWINVER=0x0A00 -D_DEBUG -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1 -DCPPGC_VERIFY_HEAP
-DENABLE_DISASSEMBLER -DV8_TYPED_ARRAY_MAX_SIZE_IN_HEAP=64 -DOBJECT_PRINT -DVERIFY_HEAP -DV8_TRACE_MAPS -DV8_ENABLE_ALLOCATI
ON_TIMEOUT -DV8_ENABLE_FORCE_SLOW_PATH -DV8_ENABLE_DOUBLE_CONST_STORE_CHECK -DV8_INTL_SUPPORT -DENABLE_HANDLE_ZAPPING -DV8_C
ODE_COMMENTS -DV8_ENABLE_DEBUG_CODE -DV8_ENABLE_HEAP_SNAPSHOT_VERIFY -DV8_SNAPSHOT_NATIVE_CODE_COUNTERS -DV8_ATOMIC_OBJECT_F
IELD_WRITES -DV8_ENABLE_LAZY_SOURCE_POSITIONS -DV8_SHARED_RO_HEAP -DV8_WIN64_UNWINDING_INFO -DV8_ENABLE_REGEXP_INTERPRETER_T
HREADED_DISPATCH -DV8_SHORT_BUILTIN_CALLS -DV8_EXTERNAL_CODE_SPACE -DV8_ENABLE_MAGLEV -DV8_ENABLE_SYSTEM_INSTRUMENTATION -DV
8_ENABLE_ETW_STACK_WALKING -DV8_ENABLE_WEBASSEMBLY -DV8_ALLOCATION_FOLDING -DV8_ALLOCATION_SITE_TRACKING -DV8_ADVANCED_BIGIN
T_ALGORITHMS -DV8_STATIC_ROOTS -DV8_USE_ZLIB -DV8_ENABLE_WASM_SIMD256_REVEC -DV8_ENABLE_CHECKS -DV8_COMPRESS_POINTERS -DV8_C
OMPRESS_POINTERS_IN_SHARED_CAGE -DV8_31BIT_SMIS_ON_64BIT_ARCH -DV8_ENABLE_SANDBOX -DV8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS -DV8_IMMINENT_DE
PRECATION_WARNINGS -DCPPGC_CAGED_HEAP -DCPPGC_YOUNG_GENERATION -DCPPGC_POINTER_COMPRESSION -DV8_TARGET_ARCH_X64 -DV8_HAVE_TA
RGET_OS -DV8_TARGET_OS_WIN -DDEBUG -DENABLE_SLOW_DCHECKS -DV8_RUNTIME_CALL_STATS -DU_USING_ICU_NAMESPACE=0 -DU_ENABLE_DYLOAD
=0 -DUSE_CHROMIUM_ICU=1 -DU_ENABLE_TRACING=1 -DU_ENABLE_RESOURCE_TRACING=0 -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -DICU_UTIL_DATA_IMPL=IC
U_UTIL_DATA_FILE -I../.. -Igen -I../../include -Igen/include -I../../third_party/icu/source/common -I../../third_party/icu/s
ource/i18n /WX /wd4244 /Gy /FS /bigobj /utf-8 /Zc:sizedDealloc- /wd4117 /D__DATE__= /D__TIME__= /D__TIMESTAMP__= /MDd /wd424
5 /wd4267 /wd4324 /wd4701 /wd4702 /wd4703 /wd4709 /wd4714 /wd4715 /wd4718 /wd4723 /wd4724 /wd4800 /wd4506 /wd4091 /wd4127 /w
d4251 /wd4275 /wd4312 /wd4324 /wd4351 /wd4355 /wd4503 /wd4589 /wd4611 /wd4100 /wd4121 /wd4244 /wd4505 /wd4510 /wd4512 /wd461
0 /wd4838 /wd4995 /wd4996 /wd4456 /wd4457 /wd4458 /wd4459 /wd4200 /wd4201 /wd4204 /wd4221 /wd4245 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4389 /w
d4702 /wd4701 /wd4703 /wd4661 /wd4706 /wd4715 /O2 /Ob2 /Oy- /Zc:inline /Gw /std:c++17 /TP /GR- /std:c++17 /Fd"obj/v8_compile
r_cc.pdb"
../..\src/compiler/node.h(341): error C3615: constexpr function 'v8::internal::compiler::Effect::Effect' cannot result in a
constant expression
../..\src/compiler/node.h(343): note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
../..\src/compiler/node.h(343): note: see usage of 'v8::internal::FlagValue<bool>::operator T'
        with
        [
            T=bool
        ]
../..\src/compiler/node.h(357): error C3615: constexpr function 'v8::internal::compiler::Control::Control' cannot result in
a constant expression
../..\src/compiler/node.h(359): note: failure was caused by call of undefined function or one not declared 'constexpr'
../..\src/compiler/node.h(359): note: see usage of 'v8::internal::FlagValue<bool>::operator T'
        with
        [
            T=bool
        ]
```

**Is V8 version 11.x still buildable using Visual Studio (2019)?
Or what needs to be done to build it?**

The overall build procedure described here is probably ok since v8 9.99 builds and runs without any issues using the steps above.

Comment: Chromium switched to `Clang` more than a year ago. So by default, it will use `Clang`. So it's most likely that VC++ compiler is either not tested or nor supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> has the V8 team switched to using clang on Windows entirely?

Yes, a long time ago.

> I get the impression that V8 is not CI tested on Visual Studio anymore.

That impression is incorrect, there's an [MSVC builder](https://ci.chromium.org/p/v8/builders/ci/V8%20Win64%20-%20msvc%20-%20builder) and it is being kept happy. I'm not sure which version of Visual Studio it's using, could be 2019.

Configurations beyond the one used by this builder are community-supported. You are welcome to [contribute a patch](https://v8.dev/docs/contribute).

---

Side note: there is nothing special to "version 10". Release branches are created on a calendar-based schedule, and we simply use "10.0" after "9.9" (and there never was a "9.99"); [see here](https://v8.dev/docs/version-numbers) for more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I highly appreciate your work, V8 is an awesome project. Is there any way to see what MSVC version and gn configuration the MSVC builder is currently using? I guess that the builder has already been updated to MSVC 2022 already. You're right, version 9.99 doesn't exist, I was referring to 9.9.x. I might take a look into this build issue but probably it's easier to wait until MSVC 2022 is supported for my use case (Unreal Engine).

Comment: I was able to find the gn arguments [0]. Sadly the compile version is not revealed in the logs and just referred to as "V8 Win64 - msvc - builder".
Eventually the reason that the CI passes might also be that the MSVC CI is not invoked with 'use_custom_libcxx=false', if this flag is relevant for MSVC at all.

- [0] https://logs.chromium.org/logs/v8/buildbucket/cr-buildbucket/8793475146407354609/+/u/build/generate_build_files/stdout?format=raw